# django pycharm error : Process finished with exit code 1

Tags: django, pycharm, windows-10, clone

I'm new to web programming. I'm sorry if the question is ridiculous. A few days ago I put my code in the git branch, today I downloaded it from the directory I received using the `git clone <git repo url>` on my laptop. I've built ENV and installed this `requirement`. But whenever I run `python manage.py runserver`, I saw the error below:
`Process finished with exit code 1`

for more information : `makemigrations` and `migrate` works correctly.

How can I fix the problem? Thanks in advance for your guidance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to run two commands before running the server .These are:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

and

```
python manage.py migrate
```

These will create the database